# Text overline in Android

Tags: java, android, text, unicode, text-decorations

Is there any way to put a line over text in Android? Since underlines and strikethroughs are possible (independent of font), it seems that overlines should be too.

I've tried using the combining overline symbol (pictured below), but it definitely looks funky. Is there a different way to achieve this?

[image: Roman Numeral Converter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is not a perfect solution. but it will give some Idea...

```
public class OverLineTextView extends TextView {

    private Paint paint;

    public OverLineTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public OverLineTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public OverLineTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        float width = getPaint().measureText(getText().toString());
        canvas.drawLine(getTotalPaddingLeft(), getTotalPaddingTop() + 1,
                getTotalPaddingLeft() + width, getTotalPaddingTop() + 1, paint);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks promising. I'm going to have to mess around with it so that only specific characters receive an overline.

Answer (score -1):

After doing enough R & D, the only way for doing that is to create a ImageView and set it dynamically to a line image and set its width with respect to the width of the textview by using `getWidth()` and position above the textview and align left with respect to the textview

Comment: This is not a good solution in case you have multi-line text.

Answer (score -3):

If you want a strikethrough on your textview ,you can do using paint flags

```
TextView textview1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textview1.setPaintFlags(textview1.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```