# Is it possible to make overline text (ā) in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-compose-textfield

I want to make text Overline, but in TextDecoration have only Underline and LineThrough styles.

I tried use TextDecoration

Comment: How to handle different character heights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overline isn't anywhere near as widely used or supported as underline or underthrough, and often looks inconsistent between different character heights.

For example using an online generator Aa becomes A̅a̅, you can see the modifier characters ([source](https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html)):

[image: overline]

If you wish to "overline" you'll need to convert the characters in your original string into the new characters. There may be a library for this, or you can manually add the modifier characters.

You'll likely need to do some sort of workaround yourself e.g. [example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19781515/608312), [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65087522/608312), but ultimately it's going to be something manual / hacky.